# how to access array when using array.prototype

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking at trying to implement the `map` function myself.

So far my code looks like this:

```js
Array.prototype.mapz = function (callback) {
    let arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       arr.push(callback(array[i]));
    }
    return arr;
};

function double(arg) {
    return arg * 2
};

const x = [1, 2, 3].mapz(double);
console.log(x); // This should be [2, 3, 6];
```

I am wondering how I can get access to the array I am mapping over in my `mapz` method?

Comment: btw, you are not mutating the original.

Comment: correct @NinaScholz updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access with [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

```js
Array.prototype.mapz = function (callback) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
       arr.push(callback(this[i]));
    }
    return arr;
};

function double(arg) {
    return arg * 2;
}

const x = [1, 2, 3].mapz(double);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54479758/accessing-arguments-in-callback-array-protoype - probably a good one for you

Answer (score 1):

Use the `this` keywork to access the array inside your function:

```js
Array.prototype.mapz = function(callback) {
    const arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
       arr.push(callback(this[i]));
    }
    return arr;
};

const x = [1, 2, 3].mapz(value => value * 2);
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `this`

```js
Array.prototype.mapz = function (callback) {
    let arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
       arr.push(callback(this[i]));
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` keyword to access the array

```js
Array.prototype.mapz = function (callback) {
    let arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
       arr.push(callback(this[i]));
    }
    return arr;
};
function double(arg) {
    return arg * 2
};
const x = [1, 2, 3,5].mapz(double);
console.log(x)
```