# accessing arguments in callback array.protoype

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am implementing the map function. To access the array I am mapping over I am using `this` based on a question I had earlier. Now I am wondering how to access different arguments passed to the `callback`. So in the official `map` method you can pass the index. I am trying to do this, but unsure how to access this in my custom method.

```js
Array.prototype.mapz = function(callback) {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    arr.push(callback(this[i]))
  }
  return arr;
};

let x = [1, 12, 3].mapz((item, index) => {
  return item * 2;
})
console.log(x);
```

Comment: where do you use `index`?

Comment: When you want to get the index in the parameter, you must *pass* it as an argument!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hand over the index as second parameter for the callback

```js
Array.prototype.mapz = function(callback) {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    arr.push(callback(this[i], i));
  }
  return arr;
};

let x = [1, 12, 3].mapz((item, index) => {
  console.log(index, item);
  return item * 2;
})
console.log(x);
```

Comment: thanks again, all makes sense. Just need it spelled out to me at the start :-D

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add another argument to your callback function which is your index.

```js
Array.prototype.mapz = function(callback) {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    arr.push(callback(this[i], i))
  }
  return arr;
};

let x = [1, 12, 3].mapz((item, index) => {
console.log(index);
  return item * 2;
})
console.log(x);
```